# Unable to update a column value in Python on Google App engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-query-language

I am able to fetch a row from a db model with condition and but unable to update a particular column in that row:

My DB model is as follow:

```
class UserDB(db.Model):
    userNickName  = db.StringProperty()
    userEmailID   = db.StringProperty()
    userID        = db.StringProperty()
    createdAt     = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    logedInAt     = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

I can check that user is exist in our UserDB model or not with following query:

```
q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT userNickName FROM UserDB WHERE userEmailID =:1", user.email())
useremailid = q.get()
if useremailid is None:
    logging.error('user is not loged in earlier so create a row for that user')
    userDB = UserDB(userNickName  = user.nickname(),
                    userEmailID   = user.email(),
                    userID        = user.user_id()
                   )
     userDB.logedInAt = datetime.now()
     userDB.put() # Insert a row for a user
 else: # User exist in our UserDB, just update `logInAt` column
     logging.error("update the login time, since user is already user")
     # How do i Update logedInAt column?
```

In the else part once I know that user is already exist in our db, I just want to update the `loginInAt` field with current timestamp, how can I do?, I search a lot on google app engine but unable to find it.

Thanks

Krishna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of your call to `q.get()` is not an id, but the actual UserDB object. So you can update it directly and save it:

```
user = q.get()
if...
else:
    user.logedInAt = datetime.now()
    user.put()
```

(UserDb is a strange name for a model class, by the way: it should be just User. And there's no need to prefix all the field names, either.)

Comment: I totally agree with your suggestion and going to update it in code. But how does it update `logedInAt` of the logged in existing user? I just wanted to perform the following sql query `UPDATE UserDB SET logedInAt =NOW() WHERE userEmailID = user.email()`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your problem at all. You get the item, change a value, and save it. How is that unclear? In any case, GQL is not SQL, and does not support UPDATE queries.

Comment: I got the problem and resolved it with the help of your above comments, actually the problem is with the query `q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT nickName FROM UserDB WHERE userEmailID =:1", user.email())` I have only selected the `nickName` and hence the following error `'Cannot put a partial entity: %s' % entity)
BadRequestError: Cannot put a partial entity: {'logedInAt': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 1, 2, 49, 45, 344570), 'userID': None, 'emailID': None, u'nickName': u'test@example.com', 'createdAt': None}`. So replace nickName with * and everything fine now. Thanks a lot for your kind help, accepted.